# Access $scope from Factory method called from template ng-click

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have my Jade file:

`button(ng-click='item.accept(item)')`

And then the `accept` method in my Factory:

```
accept = function(item) {
  return Item.update(item);
};
```

However, I'm trying to provide some sort of visual feedback to the user that `item` has been saved/updated on the server. How can I access the `$scope` object from this Factory method after `Item.update` is successful/returned?

Comment: Is `update` a resource method? Can it return a promise or callback so the view can be updated?

Comment: You can inject the $scope into your factory function.

Comment: @tymeJV It is! But then how could I access that Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

in your controller the itemClicked function will can the factory function which returns a promise(status code of the response)

```
$scope.itemClicked = function(item){
      item.accept.then(promise){
          if(promise != 200){
            $scope.item.......

      }
}
```

in item.update(item) function you can return status code  as a promise:

```
var promise = ------.then(function(response){
                              return response.status;
                          }, 
                          function(response){ 
                              return response.status;
                          });
return promise;
```